# On anti-derivative of functions

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, riemann-integration

Let $f,g,h: \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ be differentiable functions.

(1) Does there necessarily exist a differentiable function $F: \mathbb R \to \mathbb R $ such that $F'=\max \{f' ,g' \}$ ?

(2) Does there necessarily exist a differentiable function $G: \mathbb R \to \mathbb R $ such that $G '=\max \{f',g',h'\}$ ?

Answer (score 1):

Not an answer to the actual question, but note that (1) and (2) are equivalent: (2) follows from applying (1) twice since $\max\{f',g',h'\}=\max\{\max\{f',g'\},h'\}$ and (1) follows from (2) by taking $h=g$.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/1144150)

Comment: Sorry, I'll use the comment function next time. However, at the time I wrote this, I didn't have the privilege to comment anything yet, and I figured sharing my thoughts in this manner would be better than writing nothing at all.